# display json string name of json result in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

my code in unity c# is:

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    UnityWebRequest wr = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://localhost:55150/api/values");
    yield return wr.SendWebRequest();
    string a = wr.downloadHandler.text;
    Debug.Log(a);
}
```

Received response from api, As follows:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Leon","family":"ggg","des":"hhhhastam."},{"id":2,"name":"Ali","family":"dsf","des":"ali joon hastam."}]
```

how can i display names in foreach (i have fallow using litjson in project)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp)

Comment: I don't have the code right now but you can start by creating a class to serialize your json to a C# Object. You will than be able to get each property as a value

Comment: take a look to my response here (after "Final EDIT" part) This is the default way Unity works with json (you don't need any library):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51193503/converting-arrays-of-arrays-to-json/51193771#51193771

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to write a class for mirroring the entire JSON structure you could use [SimpleJSON](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON) (copy paste the `SimpleJSON.cs` into your Assets) and do something like

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    UnityWebRequest wr = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://localhost:55150/api/values");
    yield return wr.SendWebRequest();
    string a = wr.downloadHandler.text;
    Debug.Log(a);

    var jsonObject = JSON.Parse(a);
    foreach (var element in jsonObject)
    {
        var elementName = element.Value["name"];
        // do something with elementName 
        Debug.Log(elementName);
    }
}
```

---

**Update: sorting**

Since you requested also sorting: You can do that using [Linq OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.6) and [OrderByDescending](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=netframework-4.6). Luckily `SimpleJSON` already has an implementation for that so you can use `.Linq` to make `jsonObject` an `IEnumerable`:

```
using System.Linq;

//...

var jsonObject = JSON.Parse(a);
foreach (var element in jsonObject.Linq.OrderByDescending(kvp => int.Parse(kvp.Value["id"])))
{
    var elementName = element.Value["name"];
    // do something with elementName 
    Debug.Log(elementName);
}
```

**Note** that this might throw exceptions for any wrong formatted JSON string.

---

Otherwise you have to implement the whole structure as class (and a wrapper since you get a List) and can use [Unity JsonUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html)

```
[Serializable]
public class DataList
{
    public List<DataItem> items = new List<DataItem>();
}

[Serializable]
public class DataItem
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public string family;
    public string des;
}
```

and do

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    UnityWebRequest wr = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://localhost:55150/api/values");
    yield return wr.SendWebRequest();
    string a = wr.downloadHandler.text;
    Debug.Log(a);

    DataList dataList = JsonUtility.FromJson<DataList>(a);

    foreach (DataItem item in dataList.items)
    {
        // do something with element.name 
        Debug.Log(item.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much
Pay attention to the first method (simplejson)
How can I by id value orderby decending?

for example: Ali, Leon

Comment: @Leon see `Update sorting` section

Answer (score 2):

1. Define a class that represents each list item:

   ```
   class Item
   {
       public Item( Int32 id, String name, String family, String des )
       {
           this.Id     = id;
           this.Name   = name;
           this.Family = family;
           this.Des    = des;
       } 

       public Int32  Id     { get; }
       public String Name   { get; }
       public String Family { get; }
       public String Des    { get; }
   }
   ```
2. Deserialize using Json.NET (`Newtonsoft.Json`)

   ```
   using Newtonsoft.Json;

   // ...

   String jsonText = wr.downloadHandler.text;
   List<Item> itemList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>( jsonText );

   foreach( Item item in itemList )
   {
       Debug.Log( item.Name );
   }
   ```